# Could not autowire. No beans of '...' type found

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am having some problems with the implementation of a service I am creating.
Here is the one:
UserServiceImpl:

```
@Service("UserServiceImpl")
  public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceDao dao;
    public User login (LoginUser loginuser){
        return dao.login(loginuser);
    }
}
```

This is my UserService:

```
public interface UserService {
    
    public abstract User login (LoginUser loginuser);
}
```

Im getting the error  " Could not autowire. No beans of 'UserServiceDao' type found. " on UserServiceImpl.

I have another service besides this one and it has not generated any problems so far.

this is UserServiceDao :

```
public interface UserServiceDao {
public abstract User login (LoginUser loginuser);
```

}

its implementation:

```
public class UserServiceDaoImpl implements UserServiceDao{
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public User login(LoginUser loginuser) {
    User p = new User();
    String SQL = "SELECT \n" +
            "c.idclient,\n" +
            "c.dni,\n" +
            "c.clientname,\n" +
            "c.email,\n" +
            "c.clientpassword\n" +
            "FROM client as c \n" +
            "WHERE (c.email = ?) AND (c.clientpassword = ?);";
    try {
        Connection con = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ps.setString(1,"'"+loginuser.getClientemail()+"'");

        ps.setString(2, "'"+loginuser.getClientpassword()+"'");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){

            p.setClientname(rs.getString("clientname"));
            p.setDNI(rs.getString("dni"));
            p.setIdclient(rs.getString("idclient"));
            p.setClientpassword(rs.getString("clientpassword"));

        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();


    }
    return p;
}
```

}

Comment: Okay, you wrote an interface `UserServiceDao`. You haven't shown any _implementation_ for it.

Comment: thanks for the warning, I just edited it.

Comment: By the way, I hope that your custom security code is just for learning purposes; in the real world, avoid writing security code and use well-tested systems like Spring Security. You have not shown anywhere that you cause a Spring bean of `UserServiceDaoImpl` to be registered, either by using `@Component` on it or by using `@Import(UserServiceDaoImpl.class)` on an  `@Configuration`. (Finally, note that field injection like you use causes lots of problems, and it's better to use constructor injection. In that case, you don't even need `@Autowired`.)

Comment: Looks like there is no configuration or annotation to make Spring create an instance of `UserServiceDaoImpl`.

Comment: Off topic you probably don't want the single quotes you're adding around the parameters for your prepared statement.

Comment: I agree with @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- suggestion to use constructor injection.